# Build multidimensional array from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion, multidimensional-array

I would like to build a multidimensional array from an array.  For example I would like

```
$test = array (
0 => 'Tree',
1 => 'Trunk',
2 => 'Branch',
3 => 'Limb',
4 => 'Apple',
5 => 'Seed'
);
```

to become

```
$test = 
array (
   'Tree' => array (
       'Trunk' => array (
           'Branch'  => array (
               'Limb'  => array (
                   'Apple'  => array (
                       'Seed' => array ()
                   )
               )
           )
       )
   )
);
```

or more simply

```
$result[Tree][Trunk][Branch][Limb][Apple][Seed] = null;
```

I'm trying to do this with a recursive function but i'm hitting memory limit so I'm clearly doing it wrong.

```
<?php
$test = array (
0 => 'Tree',
1 => 'Trunk',
2 => 'Branch',
3 => 'Limb',
4 => 'Apple',
5 => 'Seed'
);



print_r($test);





print "results of function";

print_r(buildArray($test));



function buildArray (&$array, &$build = null)
{
    if (count($array) > 0)
    {

        //create an array, pass the array to itself removing the first value



        $temp = array_values($array);   
        unset ($temp[0]);           
        $build[$array[0]] =  $temp;


        buildArray($build,$temp);



        return $build;
    }

    return $build;


}
```

Comment: This is a good example of why recursion isn't necessarily a good idea most of the time. It is typically very easy to unwind recursion, and in doing so you get typically faster, less footprint, easier to understand code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function works recursively and does the trick:

```
function buildArray($from, $to = []) {  
    if (empty($from)) { return null; }
    $to[array_shift($from)] = buildArray($from, $to);
    return $to;
}
```

In your code I would expect you see an error. You are talking to `$build` in your first iteration as if it where an array, while you have defaulted it to `null`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an approach with `foreach` and without recursion, which works:

```
function buildArray($array)
{
    $new = array();
    $current = &$new;
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $current[$value] = array();
        $current = &$current[$value];
    }
    return $new;
}
```

[ [Demo](http://3v4l.org/cmsqY) ]

Now your function... first, using `$build[$array[0]]` without defining it as an array first produces an `E_NOTICE`.
Second, your function is going into infinite recursion because you are not actually modifying `$array` (`$temp` isn't the same), so `count($array) > 0` will be true for all of eternity.
And even if you were modifying `$array`, you couldn't use `$array[0]` anymore, because you unset that, and the indices don't just slide up. You would need `array_shift` for that.
After that, you pass `$build` and `$temp` to your function, which results in further because you now you assign `$build` to `$temp`, therefore creating another loop in your already-infinitely-recurring loop.

I was trying to fix all of the above in your code, but eventually realized that my code was now pretty much exactly the one from [Pevara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30266532/2302862), just with different variable names, so... that's that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be easy

```
$res = array();
$i = count($test);
while ($i) 
    $res = array($test[--$i] => $res);
var_export($res);
```

return

```
array ( 'Tree' => array ( 'Trunk' => array ( 'Branch' => array ( 'Limb' => array ( 'Apple' => array ( 'Seed' => array ( ), ), ), ), ), ), )
```

Comment: Interesting solution to not use pointers. Not the most efficient though.

Comment: @JohnCartwright Why  is it less efficient than calling functions?

Comment: It's nothing to do with functions. It's to do with creating copies vs references.

Comment: @JohnCartwright You have written `Not the most efficient though.` What is not effective in my code? just wondering

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: I pressed enter before finish :)

Comment: I'm describing micro optimizations, but depending on the volume it can add up to quite a bit of time and memory. By creating copies of the variables, you are relying on PHP to internally allocate memory for the variable copies. References work differently by simply referencing existing allocated memory. As the volume increases, the more memory you are allocating, the more you will rely the garbage collector to run. This is slightly simplified though.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pointer, keep re-pointing it deeper. Your two output examples gave `array()` and `null` for the deepest value; this gives `array()` but if you want `null`, replace `$p[$value] = array();` with `$p[$value] = $test ? array() : null;`

```
$test = array(
    'Tree',
    'Trunk',
    'Branch',
    'Limb',
    'Apple',
    'Seed'
);

$output = array();
$p = &$output;
while ($test) {
    $value = array_shift($test);
    $p[$value] = array();
    $p = &$p[$value];
}
print_r($output);
```